# How to save jquery selector for later use

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code...

```
$('#item_' + code + ' .delete').hide();
$('#item_' + code + ' .deleting').show();
$('#item_' + code).slideUp(400, function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('#top .message').html('Item has been deleted');
});
```

I want to save the selector I'm using in a variable and use it to perform operation instead of searching the DOM everytime.

So I save the selector like this...

```
 var saved = $('#item_' + code);
```

But how do I change the rest of the code? I'm not very familiar with jQuery, hence wondering how this can be done. Will this work...

```
$(saved).(' .delete').hide();
$(saved).(' .deleting').hide();
$(saved).slideUp(400, function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('#top .message').html('Item has been deleted');
});
```

Comment: look at my answer, you have to concatenate the selectors with variables...that will work..!

Comment: @Vivek, you don't have to advertise with a comment that you have an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll add another alternative

```
$('.delete', saved).hide();
$('.deleting', saved).show()
...
```

Comment: +1 Exactly. what I was looking for. Just didn't know the syntax. Thanks. Can you tell me how is this different from using `.find()` ?

Comment: @ShiVik, it is virtually identical

Answer (score 5):

You can use `find()`:

```
var saved = $('#item_' + code);

saved.find('.delete, .deleting').hide();
saved.slideUp(400, function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('#top .message').html('Item has been deleted');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can store it in a variable:

```
var myVar = $('#item_' + code + ' .delete').hide();
```

and then if you want to add to it just add to the var:

```
myVar.css("background","green");
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$('#item_' + code + ' .delete').hide().css("background","green");
```

Comment: +1 Useful. I can use this kind of `chaining` to improve readability. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that jQuery IS javascript. You can mix and match.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `find` or `children` methods which allow you to apply selectors to the result of a previous query.

E.g.

```
var saved = $('#item_' + code);

saved.find(".delete").hide();
saved.find(".deleting").show();
saved.slideUp(400, function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('#top .message').html('Item has been deleted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .each function on your saved selection

```
var SavedStuff = $(<something>);
// other code
SavedStuff.each( function (i, element) {
    $(element).<jquery function>;
});
```

For example:

```
var SavedStuff = $(".Square"); // save all items with Square class
// Other code
// Later, add rhomboid to all squares

SavedStuff.each( function (i, element) {
    $(element).addClass("Rhomboid");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
var saved = ('#item_' + code);

 $(saved + ' .delete').hide();
    $(saved + ' .deleting').show();
    $(saved).slideUp(400, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $('#top .message').html('Item has been deleted');
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct... I have done this to save the variable `saved = $('#item_' + code);`. So I guess `saved` will store a DOM object. Doing `saved + '.delete'` - that's like concatenating a dom object and a string. So it shouldn't work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ShiVik, apparently many people are not understand the question.

Comment: but look at my answer i have not saved dom object..'var saved = ('#item_' + code);'...so it will work fine...